Beamer presentation with one slide, containing a single image, centered horizontally and vertically
I would like to create a Beamer presentation containing a single slide.  This slide should contain the image image.png, and it should be exactly centered horizontally and vertically.  There should be nothing else on the slide.  No headers, no footers, no sidebars, no navigation buttons, nothing.
How do I do this?
This is the closest I've gotten:
\documentclass{beamer}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{image.png}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

This centers image.png from left to right, but not top-to-bottom.  There is more space below the image than above.  I suspect this is because Beamer is still leaving some vertical space for the little line of navigation buttons it normally shows, even though I've disabled the display of those buttons with \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty.
image.png is a 320x240 image, with no DPI/PPI information as far as I can tell.  (Checked with file and gwenview.)
I'm compiling to PDF with pdflatex, and viewing the resulting PDF with okular.  All under Kubuntu 22.04.

Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Thanks.  Added a description of what I've tried.

If your beamer version is up-to-date, you could use the s frame option to prevent beamer from influencing the vertical alignment and then manually add vertical fill symmetrically on the top and bottom:
\documentclass{beamer}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[s]
    \vfill
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-duck}
    \vfill
\end{frame}

\end{document}

If you need the picture to be in the absolute centre of the page, you could use tikz:
\documentclass{beamer}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-duck}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thank you!  Using tikz seems to do the trick!

@AdamL.Taylor You're welcome!
